# Showing Up 6 Minutes Late for Job Interview

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, software-industry, job-search

Today I had an interview for a junior developer role.

When I entered the address location into Google maps I did not realize I made a mistake and accidentally inputted the building address as "680" instead of "608". It took me to a building that was 3 blocks away from the actual building.

About 3 minutes before the interview was supposed to start I called my interviewer and explained to him my situation, where I was, and I personally apologized for the confusion, he told me I was about 3 blocks away and I quickly got in my car drove down 3 blocks and got to the correct building.

To make matters worse, when I got to the correct building and the floor the office was on, I did not realize that their office was under a different name than the name they had on their website and in their correspondences with me. I called the receptionist and she told me that the office was under a different name and I found it.

When I met my interviewer in person I did at first explain that my confusion came from Google maps but I again apologized for my mistake.

All in all I was about 6 minutes late for the interview, which I personally think went fairly well. Will my interviewer hold this against me?

Comment: Some interviewer would hold this against you, others wouldn't. There is no way that an internet community can tell you, which group your interviewer belongs to. However, a good interviewer will judge you mainly on the actual interview. Try to calm down and patiently wait for their feedback. Good luck!

Comment: Just to set your mind at ease - we had a candidate almost 30 minutes late because of a Google Maps error. Her interview performance caused her to be hired over the other candidates anyway. You apologised, there's nothing else to do but shine in the interview.

Comment: I was late 35 min to an interview once and got the job. I still have no idea how that happened. Some people mind, others do not.

Comment: @bharal You were fortunate.  Most companies may give you a 5 minute window, but the bottom line is you should **always** be early to an interview, period.

Answer (score 11):

> Will my interviewer hold this against me?

We can't possibly know if the interviewer will take this as something negative and affect your interview.

For the **next time, I suggest you try to be about 15-30 minutes earlier**, so you have contingency time to handle this sort of situations.

However, I think that 6 minutes late is hardly a really negative thing in this situation, as you were in constant communication with the interviewer and receptionist; they were aware of the minor mishap you made as well as the clarification on their ambiguous indications.

I would also suggest you try to keep your options open and continue your job hunt with other prospects you have, just in case this were considered an offense by the interviewer.

Comment: I would second this advice. When I interview at a company that I know well, in a location I am familiar with, I plan on 15 minutes early. For a location that's unknown, I plan on 30 - if I do end up actually arriving 30 minutes early, I wait in my car our outside and plan to walk into reception 15 minutes early. If the location is unknown but local, I do a drive-by a day or two before in order to get to know the area and the building (and parking availability, etc. etc.) My point - it never hurts to arrive early and be as prepared for the travel as for the questions in the actual interview.

Comment: @dwizum completely agree with you. Having this contingency time is best for important things like a job interview. Like they say, There is no second chance to give a first impression.

Comment: Last interview I had, I planned on 30 mins spare time. Followed my map - and then I was 10 meters away from the office building, with a massive wall between my and the building!

Comment: OP is probably also lucky that `she told me that the office was under a different name` happened, too, likely they went "oh wow oops" around that. They might even be worried about _that_ impression to the candidate!

Comment: @ElysianFields yes that is also a point in favor of OP, as it is understandable that confusion was caused by the company itself... most likely they will even update the name displayed after this incident

Answer (score 4):

> All in all I was about 6 minutes late for the interview, which I
>   personally think went fairly well. Will my interviewer hold this
>   against me?

Yes.

Maybe not blatantly. Maybe not much. Maybe not consciously. But certainly anyone who is late for an interview starts off on the wrong foot. The interviewer must factor that into things. The fact that the interviewer went ahead with the interview anyway tells us that the mistake was most likely not fatal (I know several folks who wouldn't have continued with the interview if you were late at all.)

Likely it won't matter that much. And if your interview went well, it may quickly be forgotten. Promptness is only one attribute of many against which you will be judged. And depending on the nature of the job, this may not be a significant attribute.

As @DarkCygnus wrote "There is no second chance to give a first impression." Interviewees should try hard not to be late.

Hopefully, this will be a good lesson for your future. Be more careful using Google Maps. Whenever possible, do a dry run to the interview site. Leave much earlier, so that you can arrive on time even in the face of obstacles. Basically, make it a priority to be there on time.

For now, put your arrival in the past - you can't do anything about it now. If you get called for a second interview, arrive promptly and knock it out of the park.

Comment: Same thing applies for virtual interviews: you should test your connection, skype, etc., before to be sure there would be no problem on the day of the interview